# How can I run a circuit with qucs?

Tags: qucs

I find this program, qucs, that looks very interesting. But it seems counterintuitive and I can't get it to work. I did this simple circuit

[image]

But when I said to qucs to run it, it gave an unspecified error...

[image]

what am I doing wrong? I'm very interested in working with this program and I spent hours trying ti understand what to do. But in vain.

Comment: Add a ground reference? (Most electronics simulators want one.)

Comment: Qucs sucks, try this https://tinyurl.com/yzpyjlvf

Answer (score 3):

According to qucs beginner's tutorial PDF, you need a ground reference.

Comment: Where can one find this PDF?

Answer (score 1):

A capacitor value of only 1pF is nothing. Try 1uF which is a million times more.
Then when the battery is applied the capacitor will be fully charged in about 0.00025 of a second.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a simulation from the simulations tab. So here you probably want to do a transient simulation.

[image: Simulations tab]

Further you need to add a ground node to your schematic.

Finally, for the capacitor you need to set an initial condition. You can do this in the capacitors properties.

[image: Capacitor properties]